# doxygen not producing output from input filter (doxyqml)

Tags: qml, doxygen, doxywizard

I'm trying to use [doxyqml](http://agateau.com/projects/doxyqml/) to produce QML documentation through doxygen, but the documentation pages are not being created.

As per the doxyqml documentation I've added a `*.qml` entry to `FILE_PATTERNS`, and added `*.qml=doxyqml` to `FILTER_PATTERNS` (doxyqml is available from `/usr/bin` so just calling `doxyqml` on the command line is sufficient to launch it).

From the doxygen output I can see that the `*.qml` file pattern is working as the files appear in the 'Reading' stage of the output - but *not* the parsing stage.  If I add a `#define` or some other non-QML statement to the files then a doxyqml error appears in the doxygen output, so I know that doxyqml is being called correctly.

I also know that the doxyqml output is correct because if I copy the output from calling doxyqml directly with one of the qml files, and paste it into a `*.h` file, doxygen builds the documentation for it.

It's almost as if doxygen is just not reading the output from doxyqml.  Has anyone else had this experience?  I'm using doxygen 1.8.8 and the latest doxyqml codebase (7th July 2014).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems to be because Doxygen uses the file extension to work out what parser to use to analyse the text, and because `*.qml` is new to it, it was guessing wrong (though I don't know which it was attempting to use).

The solution was to tell Doxygen which parser to use for QML files, so I just needed to add `qml=c++` to `EXTENSION_MAPPING`, and then everything worked as expected.